# URLSearchParams.get() is returning partial value

Tags: javascript, html, url, frontend

I am trying to get value from the URL using js. Everything works fine but when the URL containing any space then it is capturing only the value before that space char.

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
// An example url is https://localhost:3000/all_posts?city=%27Auburn%27&catagory=%27Bus%20&%20Trucks%27

let catagory = searchParams.get("catagory");
console.log(catagory);
```

It returns **'Bus** only

How can I get the full value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the space, the problem is with the `&` character.
`&` character in the `URL` has the separator role for the `query string` so you need to change `&` with `%26`.